# Android ListView that contains images instead of text

Tags: android, image, listview

I want to make an app for Android in Eclipse, when the user clicks a button, a camera component is opened and the user takes a picture and clicks save, after that I want that picture that he just took to show in a list. Then if he takes another picture, the picture shows below the first picture and just like that.

I know how to write the code for the camera element, but how can I do that when the user saves the picture that he just took, it would appear in the listview?

Something just like a listview with text and a TextEdit, but instead of text it would be an image and instead of TextEdit it would be the camera component.

Can you help me guys? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. Just create a custom adapter which inflates a row.xml (containing an imageview) in it's getView() method and set the image in there.

There are many many examples of how to do this, and lots on stackoverflow itself. [This](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html) is a nice example of creating a custom adapter with an imageview and listview.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't really know how to write all that code, can you show me how it should look? Thanks!